# Difference between AppUrl and sslUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

what is AppUrl and ssl url in asp.net core on visual studio? and difference between AppUrl and sslurl?

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXV2v.png)

whenever i run the application on visual studio and its always navigate to ssl url? why?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between HTTP and HTTPS is security. "S" at the and means secure and HTTPS pages use encryption for data.

I guess in your Startup.cs file in Configure method, you use something like "app.UseHttpsRedirection();". This line of code ensures that every traffic on
your HTTP page is redirected to the HTTPS page for extra safety. I think that if you remove that line, you will be able to access HTTP page.

I am sorry if I misunderstood your question.